# How to stop output from AT command in a shell line

Tags: linux, shell

I have this issue. I try to get output from `AT` command from my modem, using Linux. I get the output, but I don't know how to stop the output.

The line is some like this:

```
echo -e 'AT+CGMI' > /dev/ttyUSB3 | cat /dev/ttyUSB3
```

and the output is continuous.

I can only stop the output by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

This is the example of output:

```
OK
AT+CGMI
Nokia
OK
AT+CGMI
Nokia
OK
AT+CGMI
Nokia
OK
^C
```

I want to get only one, some like this:

```
AT+CGMI
Nokia
OK
```

Comment: What is the `... | cat /dev/ttyUSB3` supposed to do? Do you mean `echo -e 'AT+CGMI' > /dev/ttyUSB3; cat /dev/ttyUSB3`?